# Use teamviewer over the internet through a proxy on the remote end

Tags: windows, teamviewer

I work as a Technical Services person for a instrument company. The instrument uses a pc as a controller, and due to the sensitive nature of the software used to control the equipment we don't recommend the controller be on the internet. However many of our customers need the ability to move the large datasets to another machine on their network, so we offer a proxy pc as a alternative.

So they setup a pc with network access and internet access and full av and malware firewall etc. Then we put a second nic with a crossover cable to the controller pc on a different subnet, the controller pc has no firewall or av, and can only write to a shared drive on the proxy.

However we also want to be able to access the controller pc through team viewer since this is the corporate tool we have licenses for.

Can we simply punch through ports 5398, 80, 443? But will that give a route to the internet for the controller pc?

Comment: The simplest solution may be to either use Remote Desktop or have TeamVIewer connect to the controller PC's IP address from the proxy PC. TeamViewer's full version will need to be installed on the proxy PC for this to work. Use the IP address instead of a TeamViewer ID. It just means you would need to have two remote sessions open.

Comment: @worthwelle - can you use TeamViewer with an IP address? I understood all communications went through there servers.

Comment: That is correct it's not, however the proxy pc is connected to the internet. So mainly I need to know if it's possible to route just the teamviewer connection through to the controller pc without exposing it to the internet or other pc's on the network.

Comment: @davidgo It can if it is configured to do so [in the options](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Can-TeamViewer-be-used-within-a-local-network-LAN-only/ta-p/4618).